# What can I gain from this area, Academia?

Tags: discussion

I just joined Stackoverflow today. And this area, Academia is the first section where I just came into. As I know, Stackoverflow is for Q&A among users, such as a coder.

-What is the difference between 'Asking something I want to know in a Q&A section' and 'Asking here'?
-What can I do here exactly?

Comment: Welcome to AC.se. each stack exchange site caters to a different community. Take a look at our [help].

Answer (score 5):

All of your questions are covered in the [about](https://academia.stackexchange.com/about) page.